# Python how can I patch a classmethod so I can access the cls variable

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, patch

I am interested in patching the a classmethod called _validate in a Schema class and in a replaced fn using the value of cls and the other arguments.

For context ArrayHoldingAnyType inherits from Schema and _validate is called when it is instantiated.
When I try it with the below code, the value for cls is not a class. How do I fix the cls variable?

```
    def test_validate_called_n_times(self):
        def replacement_validate(cls, *args):
            # code which will return the correct values

        with patch.object(Schema, '_validate', new=replacement_validate) as mock_validate:
            path_to_schemas = ArrayHoldingAnyType(['a'])
            # I will check that the mock was called a certain number of times here with specific inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was that the classmethod decorator was missing from replacement_validate.
This fixes it:

```
    def test_validate_called_n_times(self):
        @classmethod
        def replacement_validate(cls, *args):
            # code which will return the correct values

        with patch.object(Schema, '_validate', new=replacement_validate) as mock_validate:
            path_to_schemas = ArrayHoldingAnyType(['a'])
            # I will check that the mock was called a certain number of times here with specific inputs
```

Comment: Hmm now running into an issue where mock_validate.call_args_list cannot be checked when using `new=replacement_validate` or `side_effect=replacement_validate`